# ARC with CGColorRef

Tags: iphone, automatic-ref-counting

I'm still getting used to ARC and the bridge casts.  I saw this in the docs about CGColor

> The Compiler Handles CF Objects Returned From Cocoa Methods The
>   compiler understands Objective-C methods that return Core Foundation
>   types follow the historical Cocoa naming conventions (see Advanced
>   Memory Management Programming Guide). For example, the compiler knows
>   that, in iOS, the CGColor returned by the CGColor method of UIColor is
>   not owned. You must still use an appropriate type cast, as illustrated
>   by this example:

```
NSMutableArray *colors = [NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:(id)[[UIColor darkGrayColor] CGColor]];
[colors addObject:(id)[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
```

So in my code, I tried this:

```
gradientLayer.backgroundColor = (id)([UIColor clearColor].CGColor));
```

I got a compiler warning about ARC and needed to use a bridge cast.  I still don't understand why.  When I clicked on "Fix-It", it gave me this:

```
gradientLayer.backgroundColor = (__bridge CGColorRef)((__bridge id)([UIColor clearColor].CGColor));
```

Which I do not understand.  What does this mean?  Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use `gradientLayer.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor].CGColor;` as `.CGColor` is already a `CGColorRef`. Your last code did a cast from a `CGColorRef` to a `id` and back.